# elastic search sorting first then aggregating will cause the sorting to fail

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a beginner in elasticsearch, I want to implement a function, there is an es_game to save the information of all games, I need to query the data of all games in reverse order of time, but if the game_id is the same, only a new one will be returned,
The following is my dsl method, but the returned data is not the latest,It seems that sorting first and then aggregating will cause the sorting to fail I want to query the latest data in reverse order of time, thank you.

---

this is my error dsl

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "create_time": {
              "gte": "2023-05-01 11:56:45",
              "lte": "2023-05-31 11:56:45"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
  },

  "sort": [
    {
      "create_time": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],

  "aggs": {
    "group_by_game": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "game_id"
      },
    
      "aggs": {
        "sort_by_create_time": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "create_time": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```java
 class Game {
    private Integer gameId;
    private String createTime;
...
}
```

can you  lead me modify  elastic search dsl

Answer (score 0):

I test it your scenario and it looks fine. Am I missing something?

```
PUT test_game
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "create_time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": ["yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"]
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test_game/_bulk
{ "create":{ } }
{ "create_time": "2099-05-06 16:21:15", "game_id": 1 }
{ "create":{ } }
{ "create_time": "2079-05-06 16:21:15", "game_id": 2 }
{ "create":{ } }
{ "create_time": "2085-05-06 16:21:15", "game_id": 1 }

GET test_game/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "create_time": {
        "gte": "2023-05-01 11:56:45",
        "lte": "2100-01-31 11:56:45"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "create_time": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_game": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "game_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sort_by_create_time": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "create_time": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]